# How to achieve an authentication method FIPS 140-3?

Tags: authentication, cryptography, fips

I've been studying the FIPS 140-3 but I still have questions about how to determine if an authentication protocol is FIPS compliant or not:

1- Is RADIUS over EAP-TLS FIPS 140 compliant? I know that RADIUS uses MD5, but EAP-TLS wraps the entire RADIUS packet payload into a TLS stream. So if I configure FreeRadius to use EAP-TLS, am I OK with the standard?

2- SSHv2 looks like to be configurable in a FIPS mode. I found this example: [Oracle Linux 7 OpenSSH Server Cryptographic Module](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp4176.pdf). However, I didn't understand if only this version of OpenSSH should be used or the most recent version of OpenSSH (with the right configuration) is OK too.

3- If it's possible using an AAA protocol, the authentication server (outside from cryptography module boundary) should be entirely FIPS compliant too?

Comment: "Fun" fact about FIPS: if you think about it from a security perspective, you're doing it wrong. FIPS might (in theory) be _about_ security, but in practice it's purely a matter of **compliance**. Because a FIPS-140-compliant system is, almost universally, going to be less secure than one designed by people who are actually _prioritizing security_ (and know what they're doing), unless some client of yours requires it, you shouldn't even attempt FIPS compliance. If you're one of the unlucky few that needs it... consult a compliance/GRC specialist.

Comment: To expand on the above comment: FIPS-140 compliance is mostly a matter of using only a very strict subset of protocols, constructions, and cryptographic primitives. The problem is, the subset in question is not remotely up to date, and prohibits using many modern solutions that address weaknesses in the old ones that FIPS permits. The reason there are FIPS-compliant versions of things like OpenSSH (and only those who need FIPS use them) is because it requires removing support for a lot of modern cryptography... and in some cases restoring support for things that are deprecated as less secure!

Comment: Hi, @CBHacking. Thx for your reply. Unfortunately, I have to use FIPS. I already know size of ciphers and so on. However, I don't know how to determine if certain configuration is FIPS compliant or not, as you can see in my cases 1 and 2. I know how to enable FIPS mode in Opessl. But considering that Openssl is ok and I disabled non-compliant algorithms from Openssh. How can I determine it is a compliant method of authentication?

Comment: That is unfortunately a compliance question, not a security question. Any library in strict FIPS mode _should_ be compliant, but you need somebody who is familiar with the standard and how auditors interpret it, if you're worried about passing an audit. That's a different specialization from security.